# Keep thread running after onDestroy

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-notifications

I am currently building an android application that will be used as an anti theft sort of application. Basically, once the alarm has bee launched, the application will monitor the accelerometer to detect movement. If it does, the user will have 15 seconds to enter a set password to deactivate the alarm, otherwise : BIIIIIP!

My problem is the following: how do I manage to keep the monitoring and counter process running after the activity is destroyed (if for example the user presses back) in a way that I can access it again from a notification.

I was thinking of using a thread to run the monitoring and counting process and when the notification was pressed, for example, the class could, in it's onCreate method, be aware whether an already existing thread is running and if so, get the handle to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). They are meant for this exact purpose; to run on the background (this does not mean a background `Thread` ) even if there are no `Activities` running.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using services for this purpose. Here is one of the example: http://blog.kozaxinan.com/2012/08/using-accelerometer-when-screen-off_16.html